# BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize documentation confusion

Tags: java, android, documentation, bitmapfactory

Following is the code from the official Android documentation.
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

I am not able to understand the use of **Math.min** function here. So what Math.min is doing, is selecting the smallest ratio between photoW/targetW and photoH/targetH.

Now, let us suppose there is an image whose width is two times larger than that of the imageView and its height is four times larger than that of the imageView. So, the ratios come to be two and four and the Math.min function will give us two in the scaleFactor.

And what bmOptions.inSampleSize does is
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options#inSampleSize

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original
> image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is
> the number of pixels in either dimension that corresponds to a single
> pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an
> image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original

According to this, our image will get half it's size whose height will still be two times bigger than that of the imageView.

Shouldn't we use **Math.max** or am I missing something?

Comment: Please do the calculation in the way you want and need.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I reported too Google. Needs  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions); before  int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;

Comment: @Style-7 Although, that was not my question but I am confused by that also.